# What is the meaning of "did enough and more" in following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives

> Donald Trump **did enough, and more**, to mess up his meeting with Vladimir Putin.

Donald trump has done more than enough. Is this the meaning of this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

He did enough to mess up his meeting with VP.

He did enough, and more, to mess up his meeting with VP.

Yes, I guess you could say it is the almost the same as **more than enough**. However, by writing it like that, it is more emphatic and stands out more fully.

Answer (score 1):

> He reached the threshold, then surpassed it.

That is the most succinct way I can think of expressing that sentence. I hope I made it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

"Enough and more" is not, I think, the most common way to express this thought.  I would have used the different idiomatic expression *enough and then some*.

> Donald Trump did **enough and then some** to turn his meeting with Vladimir Putin into an avoidable disaster.

This is one way to emphasize that Trump did *more than what was sufficient* to achieve a certain result.  The nuance is that the effort *went beyond* what would be considered an *ordinary* mistake.